# Sql query for CONVERT datetime to a different datetime Format in SQL 2005?

Tags: sql, datetime, format

My datetime column is in MM/dd/yyy format. i want this to be converted in dd/MM/yyyy, I am able to converting this datetime to narchar.

```
select convert(nvarchar,columnname,103) from dbo.table
```

i m getting my answer like "dd/MM/yyyy" but it is string. if i write **datetime** in place of **nvarchar**

i am getting "yyyy-MM-dd" whaa is the query for getting "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: Why do you want to place datetime in place of nvarchar?

Comment: That's because a `datetime`, *as* a `datetime`, has **no** format. A `datetime` value contains an internal numeric representation of a date. Formats only come into play when you convert a datetime to/from strings. And it's whilst treating datetimes as strings and believing that they *have* a format that most date related bugs are produced. If you avoid doing *any* formatting in the database itself, strive to do so.

Comment: because nvarchar is a string, and i am placing it in windows forms datagridview in c#. i want this style to enter in datagridview

Comment: Do the formatting and parsing in c#, as close as possible to the user - as early as possible for input, as late as possible for output. Everywhere else, keep it as `datetime` and remember that such items don't *have* formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

check out

see Microsoft's explanation on date formats
the one you're looking for is 20 or 120

BTW, you should supply  with  varchar with a  number like this `varchar(10)`